# Efficient ranking algorithm (in PHP)

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I have a PHP array (retrieved from a DB) of employees calculated data. There are about 10 columns per employee, 8 of them numerical (the other 2 are id and name). Here's a short sample:

```
David: 1024, 75,  22  
Mike:  500,  100, 25  
Jeff:  700,  82,  10
```

I can easily sort the array on any of the (numerical) fields to show who's at the top/bottom, but what I'd really like to show in the final table view is ranking by the value, so people won't have to sort and re-sort the table to get what they want. Here's an example of the table sorted by the first column, showing rankings in parentheses:

```
David: 1024 (#1), 75  (#3), 22 (#2)  
Jeff:  700  (#2), 82  (#2), 10 (#3)  
Mike:  500  (#3), 100 (#1), 25 (#1)
```

Now, I know the easiest approach is just to sort the table by column, use the row indexes as the ranking and repeat per every column. I just wondered if I could find a more efficient way.

I thought about using ordered queues (one per column that needs ranking), scanning the array once and pushing values into the queues. But:

1. PHP does not have any data structures other than arrays (unless you use external additions)
2. I'm not convinced this is more efficient.

Could anyone please suggest the best approach, and/or confirm I should just re-sort the array several times?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is it possible to apply your ranking criteria by changing the query you make on the database or the query is fixed and you can't modify it?

Comment: *"PHP does not have any data structures other than arrays"* True, but PHP arrays are quite flexible. I can't think of any language that has a built-in data structure that would be more suitable to this task than PHP arrays.

Comment: Have you considered just printing everything out and use Javascript to sort stuff out, [like this](http://www.webtoolkit.info/demo/sortable-table)? I think it would look less cluttered and would also be more intuitive.

Comment: not sure what you're asking here, do just want to show the ranking next to the values you print out?

Comment: @NullUserException the result is shown in a JS-created table, but I don't want to submit the user to client side sorting.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy Why is that?

Comment: @ab_dev86 That would make the initial query highly complex and self-referencing, since SQL is forward looking.

Comment: store the data in an array (associative or multi-dimensional) when you print the data out you could use `usort` or `uasort` on each "column" to apply a ranking function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after much deliberation, I decided to go the "sort every column" route.
For future reference by anyone interested, here's the function I've added to my class - it's called once per every column I need ranked:

```
   private function calculateRankings(&$employees, $columnName) {
        $comparer = "return (\$a[$columnName][0] == \$b[$columnName][0]) ? 0 :  (\$a[$columnName][0] > \$b[$columnName][0] ? -1 : 1);";
        usort($employees, create_function('$a,$b', $comparer));
        foreach($employees as $key => &$employee) {
            $employee[$columnName][1] = $key + 1;
        }
    }
```

The +1 is due to the keys being zero-based.

You prepare for this function by turning each field you need ranked into a 2-element array: the first ([0]) contains the value, and the second ([1]) will contain the rank in the end.
I.e.: `$employees['salary'] = array(1550, 0);`.
You then call the function like this:
`$this->calculateRankings($employees, 'salary');`.

I sincerely hope this helps someone, someday. Thanks to all responders/commenters!

**UPDATE 4/9:** The function I supplied before couldn't work - there's no way to pass a third parameter (in our case, the column name) into the comparer function. The only way to do it is to use a static class variable, or a create_function hack that I ended up with. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you would have to stick with the initial approach.

There is no escape from having to iterate through all the columns and compute the ranking information for each individual one.

What you could do is optimize the algorithm to accomplish that task more efficiently.

**PS.:** I don't think that the algorithm is unusual enough for you to worry about complexity, order of growth or running time, even though performance is always important.

Comment: Actually, believe there is a way to avoid iterating through the whole array again and again, using an external data structure. I can always take the shortest route - but for the sake of my CS days, I was looking for efficiency :)

Comment: Still, if you work with some specific abstract data structure, you are gonna have more processing time than you would have working with native arrays. But you can try though.